# Google Sheets: Listing and counting unique values from multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm looking to list and count unique values from multiple cells. The practical application is to list and count the scenes in a movie that a particular character appears in.

I'm using the following array formula to list the scenes from the data table:

```
=ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($B$11:$B$64=E13,$A$11:$A$64,"")))
```

It will returns something like this (these are the scene numbers):
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4

But I want it to return:
2,3,4

Then to count the unique values I used the following formula:

```
COUNTUNIQUE(SPLIT(F13,", ",0))
```

But the problem here is that it returns "1" even when the array formula correctly returns no value (i.e. the character didn't appear in any scene)

Here is the Google Sheet so you can see things in context:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dwrORFJ508duRP1no7258dqLemujkOjpvA3XmolqtsU/edit?usp=sharing

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hm.... I tried =ArrayFormula(UNIQUE(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($B$11:$B$64=E15,$A$11:$A$64,"")))) but same result. 
   
I also tried the UNIQUE function in other spots but it returns invalid results. 
   
Note that I need to first run the check (this is why there is the IF function), which then returns the list of scenes. Is there a way to apply the UNIQUE function after this check is done? If not, what can be done?

Comment: @I'-'I Ok I have something, but it's ugly..... First formula: =iferror(textjoin(", ",TRUE,unique(filter(transpose(split(ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($B$11:$B$64=$E13,$A$11:$A$64,""))),", ",0)),transpose(split(ArrayFormula(TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($B$11:$B$64=$E13,$A$11:$A$64,""))),", ",0))))),"None") ...... For the count when no scenes are found, I didn't understand your suggestion, but used this (also ugly): =if($F17="None",0,COUNTUNIQUE(SPLIT($F17,", ",0))), which is depending on the previous formula..... If there is no cleaner way to do this I will post my own answer. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F11:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",1,UNIQUE(IF(E11=B$11:B,A$11:A,))))
=COUNT(SPLIT(F11,","))
```

- Use `UNIQUE()` to find unique values before joining them
- SPLIT parameter 1 can't be empty, which gives a #VALUE error,Which is counted as 1 with  COUNTUNIQUE.Use  IFERROR to mask it.(Since we already have unique values, COUNT is simpler)

Comment: @|'-'| Thanks - I see what you meant now :) I decided to return "None" in case there is no value returned. I am working on it but can't figure it out. For some reason, ISBLANK does not return TRUE even though the cell looks blank. Still trying...

Comment: @|'-'|  Yes it definitely works. Now I'm just trying to figure out how to return "None" instead of the cell looking blank.

Comment: @|'-'|  Ok, I have figured out how to return "None" instead of the cell looking blank. I used the EQ formula, and left value2 empty. The resulting formula is: =if(eq(ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",1,UNIQUE(IF(E17=B$11:B,A$11:A,)))),),"None",ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",1,UNIQUE(IF(E17=B$11:B,A$11:A,)))))   .........  Maybe there's a more elegant way but looks like it works.

Comment: ooops! haha Got it.